# Close modal by clicking outside of it, pressing escape, or pressing the closing X in the corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal dialog that I'd like to close by clicking outside of it, pressing escape, or pressing the closing X in the corner.

I already have the pressing X in the corner part working. Just need the others.

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2, and jQuery 1.9.1

My JsFiddle is at:

http://jsfiddle.net/HUD8V/

Since I have to post some code with a fiddle (makes no sense, the fiddle has the code...)

CSS is:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.closeModal {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.closeModal:hover {background:#00d9ff;}
```

Comment: What's wrong with TWBS built-in modal box?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Is there a built in modal I don't know about that I should be using? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, there is, check this out: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: If i'm honest, I don't know how you have got your modal working, even looking through your external JS file, I can't find any events to get this working. Can you show us the specific JS you have written for the modal?